# On a dedicated hot water recirculation line can you reduce the diameter of the line at a certain point?

Tags: plumbing, copper, copper-tubing, copper-pipe

Our dedicated recirc line/race track is essentially square shaped with 8' sides. However our sink/dishwasher (1.5TFU) is 25' developed length away. A 50' round trip to make it back to the "square" portion of the race track.

Since this 50' portion of the race track is exposed to indirect UV light we decided we were going to use copper for this portion and pex-b for everything else.

The "square" portion of the race track needs to be 3/4" however the 25' portion to the sink/dishwasher technically only needs to be 1/2" to deliver the correct pressure.

My question is, can you have a portion of your recirc line 3/4" and another part it of 1/2" or do you need to have the entire race track a consistent internal diameter?

Asking because copper prices are pretty high. Not trying to cheap out - I just don't want to get 3/4" if I don't need to.